# Localization with native controls in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, localization, internationalization

I am creating a multilingual app in IOS. My app supports 4 languages (en,zh,ja&pt). Through my app user can able to change the language with this approach as label & text are localized with user selected language but the native controls Like (Email, print & context menu) are always display in english, how can I change the native controls labels with my own text.

Please advice...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you providing the ability for you users to change the language in your app?

I would recommend you check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/#resources)

As you should use the localization capabilities that Apple provides you with i.e. set the language based on that of the device it's running on. If you app doesn't support a particular language then it will display in the default language for your app.

If you're using elements of UIKIt or another apple framework apple has included more languages than you have, so these elements will display in the chosen language of the device their running on. You shouldn't try to change that!

Answer (score 0):

Is your user changing the device language in settings, along with the region?  Some of the native stuff is keyed off the device language settings->International->Language and the Region format.  Apple has left this in the hands of the user, so its native labels will display in the user's chosen language.